# How is the correct way to exapand braces in a "for loop" BASH to positional parameters?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, expansion, braces

When I try write this function in BASH

```
function Odds () for i in {1..${#@}..2} ; do echo $i; done
```

I expected for an output like

> 1 3 5...

depending on number of arguments passed to the function.

But the efective output is the string with ${#@} expanded.

Ex

> {1..5..2}

I have some conjectures but... any away... what is happing and how to avoid this and get the desirable output?

Comment: Have you tried [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that *brace expansion* is done **before** *parameter substitution*.  Consequently, *brace expansion* can't be used with variables.

#### Option 1: seq

If you have `seq` installed (this is common on Linux), try:

```
function Odds () { seq 1 2 "${#@}"; }
```

`seq 1 2 "${#@}"` returns numbers starting with `1` and incremented by `2` each time until `${#@}` is reached.

For example:

```
$ Odds a b c d e
1
3
5
```

*Note:*  The `function` notation isn't necessary and limits compatibility (it's not POSIX).  `Odds` can be defined without it:

```
Odds () { seq 1 2 "${#@}"; }
```

#### Option 2: bash

Alternatively, just using bash, define:

```
function Odds () { for ((i=1; i<=${#@}; i=i+2)); do echo "$i"; done; }
```

This produces the same output:

```
$ Odds a b c d e
1
3
5
```

#### Option 3: POSIX

For widest compatibility, use a function that meets the POSIX standard:

```
Odds() { i=1; while [ "$i" -le "$#" ]; do echo "$i"; i=$((i+2)); done; }
```

Comment: I have really liked your comments. Specially this one : "The problem is that brace expansion is done before parameter substitution."

 I was trying avoiding using `seq` , looking for a more "pure" bash code. Anyaway, thank you!

For studying proporse, I am try to learn the most portable coding way.

Comment: @DanielBandeira For most portable, one should use code that meets the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html).   That's the (newly added) Option 3 above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function Odds () { for i in {1..${@}..2} ; do echo $i; done }
```

or

```
function Odds () { for i in {1..${1}..2} ; do echo $i; done }
```